# Instantiate ArrayList inside class constructor

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class as follows:

```
package com.aci.golfgames;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Course {
    private String name;
    private int noOfTees;
    private ArrayList<Tee> tees;

    public Course(){
        // Build a course with some tees.
        name = "ABC Country Club";
        ArrayList<Tee> tees = new ArrayList<Tee>();
        tees.add(new Tee("White", 126, 70.4));
        tees.add(new Tee("Red", 128, 75.2));
        tees.add(new Tee("Blue", 126, 71.4));
        noOfTees = 3;
    }

    public String getCourseName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public ArrayList<Tee> getTees(){
        return tees;
    }
    public int getNoOfTees(){
        return this.noOfTees;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to instantiate the ArrayList field *tees*, it seems that I am creating a different ArrayList than the one declared as a field in the Object *Course*. IOW, *this.tees* is different than *tees*. If I remove the line:

```
            ArrayList<Tee> tees = new ArrayList<Tee>();
```

I get a Null Pointer exception at runtime at the *tees.add(...)*, I assume because the ArrayList has not been instantiated.

What's wrong here? How do I instantiate the ArrayList? Note:the number of entries in the *tees* ArrayList will change from object to object, hence the ArrayList instead of just an array. The code here is just to define one *Course* for testing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public Course(){
    ArrayList<Tee> tees = new ArrayList<Tee>();
}
```

Should be

```
public Course(){
    tees = new ArrayList<Tee>();
}
```

By defining it as `ArrayList<Tee>` again inside the constructor, you're reducing the scope of `tees` in the constructor to the constructor only, while the other methods are using `tees` that is defined as a field at instance scope.

So yes, it will in effect create a new list which will be used inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you're creating a locally-scoped `ArrayList` inside the constructor that is shadowing the outer `tee`. You need to do:

```
tees = new ArrayList<Tee>();
```

That is, get rid of the preceding `ArrayList<Tee>`.

Also consider using the interface `List<Tee>` instead of `ArrayList<Tee>` for the type of `tee`; this will make it easy for you to swap implementations later since you are not tightly-coupled to `ArrayList`.